# Chance getting a shiny

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

I’m breeding a Pokémon from my region and a Pokémon from another region. Is the chance of getting a shiny higher or still the same?

Comment: Note that it's specifically two parents from different *languages*. The region doesn't matter, and it doesn't matter if either of them are your own as long as they're different from each other.

Answer (score 0):

Its going to be higher because of the [Masuda Method](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Masuda_method).

> The Masuda method involves breeding two Pokémon created in games of different languages. An Egg resulting from such a pairing will have a higher likelihood of being Shiny.

Comment: What is the masuda method?